# Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want my images which will be moving on the screen to get blasted,say I am writing an application where a balloon is moving on my emulator from bottom to top and on touching, the  balloon,it should burst. Is that possible for me?If so how do I write the code for the bursting of the image on touching it? (here image is balloon).Any help would be appreciated,I am in real need of it..

Comment: you should probably use OpenGL